# How to print the stack of the app under android?

Tags: android, delphi, firemonkey

I can detect when the app freeze (I have a background thread which periodically checks if the main thread is responsive). Now when I detect that the app is frozen, I would like to save on a file the stack of the main thread to know where it's frozen and try to understand why. I'm under android on delphi berlin. Is this possible to do?

Answer (score 0):

You can get the stack elements using:

```
StackTraceElement[] stackTraceElements = new Throwable().getStackTrace();
```

and then print the individual elements.

Comment: It is :)  Guess I'm operating under the assumption that Delphi gives you some access to the underlying java.

Comment: It does. Even that won't allow you to get this code to run in a thread which is hung.

Comment: I guess that the object above can be found somewhere in Androidapi.JNI.??? (delphi)

Comment: As @DavidHeffernan pointed out, this won't solve your problem unless you can get it run on the main thread, perhaps by triggering an exception or something.

Comment: @DavidBerry yes it's impossible to get it run on the main thread because the main thread is hanging :( no problem from delphi to run this function, just that it's impossible from the main thread when it's hang